# How to install .patch file

Tags: kernel, wine, patch

I want to install World of Tanks, and I'm following this tutorial https://worldoftanks.eu/en/content/soft/pc_programs/1311/

There is a thing with raw input mouse, and I don't know how to install it, the file name is raw3.patch and it's on desktop, and I always get this error :

```
~/Desktop$ patch -p1 < raw3.patch 
can't find file to patch at input line 11
PerhAaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
```

The text leading up to this was:

```
--------------------------
|commit 51e1810634de2c212e6515fbfb2ea92a3e2409ad
|Author: Vincas Miliūnas <vincas.miliunas@gmail.com>
|Date:   Wed Feb 22 21:48:26 2012 +0200
|
|    RAW
|
|diff --git a/dlls/user32/input.c b/dlls/user32/input.c
|index 050fb2b..23ad6f7 100644
|--- a/dlls/user32/input.c
|+++ b/dlls/user32/input.c
--------------------------
```

File to patch:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a patch file that is meant to be applied to the source code of wine before compiling.

To do that, read up on how to compile wine and apply the patch (through the command you already found) before compiling and installing wine.